# Is the commonly worn undershirt known as a "beged tzitzit" actually obligated in tzitzit at all?

Tags: halacha, talmud-gemara, tzitzis, bracha-levatala

> What is meant by ‘a garment exempt from tzitzit’? Does it mean a garment smaller than the prescribed measure? But it has been taught: A garment with
>   which a child can cover his head and most of his body, **and in which a grown-up person would walk out for a moment**, is subject to tzitzit  (Talmud Bavli, Menachot 40b-41a)

I wouldn't walk outside wearing only [that flimsy sleeveless undershirt.](http://www.mazorguide.com/images/Living/tzitzit.jpg)  It's not modest dress at all, even for a man.  I don't think most observant Jewish men would walk from their front door to the curb to pick up the newspaper, wearing only that undershirt.

That being the case, wouldn't this mean that the so-called "beged tzitzit" is not really obligated in tzitzit, and one does not receive the reward of doing a mitzvah for wearing it?

Is it a bracha l'vatala (blessing in vain) to make the blessing "al mitzvat tzitzit" on such a garment?

Comment: And can you wear it outside an Eruv on Shabbat?

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/11302/do-married-men-stop-saying-a-bracha-on-their-tallit-katan?lq=1#comment23375_11303 http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/12810/tallit-katan-and-tallit-brachot?lq=1#comment23374_12814 Also see Darkei Moshe OC 8:5 and Arukh haShulchan / Tzitz Eliezer about minimum shiur for undershirts.

Comment: related http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/3532/759

Comment: this 6aleeth qo6on is not a baghadh and therefore does not require 9i9ith. if you want to wear a 9i9ith all day, do so how it was done originally: http://www.hydepark.co.il/upload0708/2008116_2017296310_%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%AA%20001.jpg https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xaf1/t1.0-9/10489887_270587229816256_7983652463109973592_n.jpg http://www.nosachteiman.co.il/_uploads/extraimg/2m4.jpg http://cache.hydepark.co.il/upload0708/2008116_20165630070_%D7%98%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%AA.jpg

Comment: @jake saying a barocho on such a 6aleeth is indeed a barocho laba6olo. and wearing one would be considered carrying on shabboth. some even would go as far as to say the way jews wear their 6aleetoth now a days would be considered carrying on shabboth as well for it is not lahith3a6eif

Comment: Related Q&A https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/80491/7303

Answer (score 4):

**Halachic aspects:**

The Aruch haShulchan in Orach Chaim -  סימן ח - דיני ציצית ועטיפתו  - brings the Bet Yosef who says that our small Talit Kattan is a valid garment that fully fulfills that requirements for Tzitzith.

Here's what he write in Siman ז for example:

> ואחר כך כתב רבינו הבית יוסף בסעיף ג: ‏
>
> טליתות קטנים שלנו, שאנו נוהגים אף על פי שאין בהם עיטוף – יוצאין בהם ידי חובת ציצית. עד כאן לשונו. ‏

The discussion in the Poskim is how to deal with the Ituf - wrapping it around the head & shoulders - but not about it being valid for Bracha and Shabbat.

Though *which* Bracha to say is part of the discussion.

The Shulchan Aruch (ibid) writes similarly:

> טַלִּיתוֹת קְטַנִּים שֶׁלָּנוּ שֶׁאָנוּ נוֹהֲגִים לִלְבֹּשׁ, אַף עַל פִּי שֶׁאֵין בָּהֶם עִטּוּף, יוֹצְאִים בָּהֶם יְדֵי חוֹבַת צִיצִית, וְטוֹב לְהַנִּיחַ אוֹתוֹ עַל רֹאשׁוֹ רָחְבּוֹ לְקוֹמָתוֹ, וּלְהִתְעַטֵּף בּוֹ, וְיַעֲמֹד כָּךְ מְעֻטָּף לְפָחוֹת כְּדֵי הִלּוּךְ ד' אַמּוֹת, וְאַחַר כָּךְ יִמְשְׁכֶנּוּ מֵעַל רֹאשׁוֹ, וְיִלְבְּשֶׁנּוּ. ‏

Even regarding Shabbat in סימן יג - דיני ציצית בשבת we learn:

> **ב** אִם הִיא מְצֻיֶּצֶת כְּהִלְכָתָהּ, מֻתָּר  לָצֵאת בָּהּ לִרְשׁוּת הָרַבִּים, בֵּין טַלִּית קָטָן בֵּין  טַלִּית גָּדוֹל: אֲפִלּוּ בַּזְּמַן הַזֶּה שֶׁאֵין לָנוּ תְּכֵלֶת ‏

**Discussions:**

The Be'er Heitev already touches on your question in סימן טז - שעור טלית.

The Aruch Hashulchan discusses the Gemara you mention at length in סימן טז - דין כמה שיעור אורך הטלית ורחבו.

His conclusion is that the size of a "grown-up person would walk out for a moment" refers to outer garments and not to under-garments like out Arba-kanfot.

It's a long piece - 5 simanim long - and discussed the various Rishonim and how they deal with your question.

For completeness I'll paste the sources - but it's too convoluted to translate:

Shulchan Aruch:

> סימן טז - שעור טלית, ובו סעיף אחד
>
> **א** שִׁעוּר טַלִּית שֶׁחַיָּב בְּצִיצִית שֶׁיִּתְכַּסֶה בּוֹ בְּאֹרֶךְ וּבְרֹחַב רֹאשׁוֹ (א) וְרֻבּוֹ שֶׁל קָטָן הַמִּתְהַלֵּךְ לְבַדּוֹ בַּשּׁוּק, וְאֵינוֹ צָרִיךְ אַחֵר לְשָׁמְרוֹ: הגה: וְאָז חַיָּב בְּצִיצִית וְדַוְקָא שֶׁהַגָּדוֹל לוֹבְשׁוֹ פְּעָמִים (ב) עַרְאַי וְיוֹצֵא בּוֹ לַשּׁוּק (בֵּית יוֹסֵף בְּשֵׁם בֶּן חָבִיב וּבְשֵׁם מַהֲרִי''א): ‏
>
> באר היטב  (**א**) ורובו של קטן. היינו כשהוא בן ט' בתשו' רמ''א מפלפל האיך יוצאין בד' כנפות הקטנים מזה השיעור ותי' דמוטב לילך בהם מלילך כל היום בלא ציצית ובד''מ סי' ט' כ' ללמד העם שיברכו בבוקר על טלית גדול ויפטרו את הקטן וילכו בו כל היום ומ''מ אם אפשר לאדם שיעשה גדול שהוא כשיעור מה טוב ומה נעים עכ''ל. וכ' מט''מ בשם מהרי''ל דיש לעשות הכתפים רחבים דלא ליתי אוירא דהאי גיסא ודהאי גיסא ויבטל ליה. מ''א. ובספר פרי הארץ כ' בשם ספר דרך חכמה ששיעורו ג' רבעי אמה באורך וחצי אמה ברוחב ושיעור טלית גדול הוא שיכסה ראשו ורובו בעטיפה ויגיע עד החזה ע''ש. כ' האר''י ז''ל טלית קטן יותר טוב שלא יהי' בו בתי זרועות אם לבש הטלית ונתקפל קצת כדרך לובשי בגדים ואחר שנתקפל אין בו כשיעור כדי להתכסות ראשו ורובו כתב בתשו' בית יעקב סק''ו דכיון שעומד להתפשט כפשוט דמי אף שלא נתפשט עדיין והרי יש בו כשיעור ע''ש ועיין בבני חייא. הטלית קטן שיש בו כדי לכסות ראשו ורובו וע''י התפירה אין בו כשיעור פטור מציצית. שם סי' ס''ו וכ''כ בלקט הקמח: (**ב**) עראי. ואם גדול מתבייש לצאת בו עראי לשוק אין לברך עליו. ואם הוא יוצא בטלית שאחרים אין יוצאין בו בטלה דעתו מ''א ועי' ט''ז עי' בשכנה''ג ובס' פרי הארץ סי' א' ובע''ת: ‏

Aruch Hashulchan:

> סימן טז - דין כמה שיעור אורך הטלית ורחבו
>
> **א** תניא במנחות דף מ עמוד ב : ‏
>
> טלית שהקטן מתכסה בו ראשו ורובו, והגדול יוצא בו דרך עראי – חייבת בציצית. אין הקטן מתכסה בו ראשו ורובו, אף על פי שהגדול יוצא בה עראי – פטורה. 
>   עיין שם. ובוודאי שיש שיעור לקטן זה, דאין סברא לומר לקטן בן שנה או שתים או מעט יותר. ובאמת כתב הרמב''ם ריש פרק שלישי: ‏
>
> קטן המתהלך לבדו בשוק ואינו צריך אחר לשומרו. 
>   עד כאן לשונו. וגם שיעור זה לא נתברר, דאין לומר דזהו קטן שאינו צריך לאמו דהוא כבן ארבע או חמש כדאמרינן בריש פרק שמיני דעירובין, דאם כן הוה ליה להרמב''ם לומר לשון זה. אלא וודאי דכוונתו לגדול מזה. ‏
>
> והטור כתב בן תשע שנים, עיין שם. ואולי יצא לו שיעור זה מפני שמצינו בש''ס (יבמות צו ב) דבן תשע ראוי לביאה – הרי שעתה יצא לכלל גדלות קצת. והנימוקי יוסף כתב: קטן המתבייש לצאת לחוץ בלא כסות, עיין שם. ‏
>
> ונראה לי כיון דהטור פירש השיעור, והמה לא פירשו – קיימא לן כהטור. ואולי גם הם סוברין כן דאלו אם באנו לשער בשיעורם – עדיין לא ידענו כמה. ‏
>
> הט''ז מביא מפעוטות, וצריך עיון. ודייק ותמצא קל. ‏
>
> **ב** והנה הרמב''ם לא הזכיר כלל הך תנאי דגדול יוצא בו דרך עראי, אלא שהקטן מתכסה בו ראשו ורובו, עיין שם. אבל הטור כתב שיעור טלית להתחייב בציצית: כל שקטן בן תשע שנים יכול לכסות בה ראשו ורובו, וגדול אינו מתבייש בה לצאת באקראי לשוק. אבל אם אין הקטן מתכסה בה ראשו ורובו, אף על פי שגדול יוצא בה באקראי לשוק – פטור. עד כאן לשונו. ‏
>
> ורבים תפסו שהרמב''ם והטור מחולקים: דהרמב''ם סבירא ליה דדי בתנאי דקטן מתכסה..., והטור סבירא ליה דתרתי בעינן. ועל פי זה כתב רבינו הרמ''א על דברי רבינו הבית יוסף שהם כלשון הרמב''ם. כתב הוא וזה לשונו: ‏
>
> ודווקא כשהגדול לובשו פעמים עראי ויוצא בו לשוק. 
>   עד כאן לשונו. וגם דקדקו: למה לא שנה התנא האופן השני, אם קטן מתכסה ואין גדול יוצא בו דרך עראי. והאריכו כל אחד לפי דרכו (עיין בית יוסף, וב''ח, ודרישה, וט''ז, ומגן אברהם). וגם חקרו איך הדין כשגדול יוצא בו בקבע ואין הקטן מתכסה בו, והסכימו דחייבת בציצית (ב''ח ומגן אברהם ואליה רבה). ובוודאי כן הוא, דבגד שגדול יוצא בו בקביעות למה יפטור? ‏
>
> **ג** אמנם לעניות דעתי כל טורח זה בחינם. דהנה זהו וודאי דכל הדינים הם לגדולים, דקטנים לאו בני מצוה נינהו. ולכן הרמב''ם לא הוצרך לפרש רק דבר של קטן שהוא לסימנא, והגדול לא הוצרך להזכיר דסתמא בגדולים מיירינן. והברייתא הכי קאמר: טלית שהקטן מתכסה בו ראשו ורובו – חייבת בציצית. והדבר תמוה: הא התורה אמרה ''אשר תכסה בה''. ולגדולים נאמרה, ופשיטא דבגד שהקטן מתכסה בו ראשו ורובו לא יספיק לגדולים, דאין דרך גדול לצאת בבגד קצר כזה, והיוצא – בטלה דעתו. וזה מתרץ הברייתא: והגדול יוצא בה דרך עראי, כלומר: אף על גב דלקביעות וודאי אינו ראוי, אבל במקרה יוצא בה, והתורה חייבה גם כשיוצא בה דרך עראי. ופסיקא להו לרבנן דכל שהקטן מתכסה בה ראשו ורובו – ראוי לגדול לעראי. אך לפי זה אולי יאמרו דלעראי ראוי אף פחות משיעור זה, לזה אומר דאם אין הקטן מתכסה בה ראשו ורובו, אף על פי שהגדול יוצא בה עראי – פטורה. אבל להיפך אי אפשר לומר, דזהו מן הנמנעות דאם רק קטן מתכסה ראשו ורובו יש לגדול עראי. ‏
>
> ונמצא דכל עיקר הדין תלוי בהקטן, ולכן לא הזכיר הרמב''ם יותר. והטור העתיק לשון הגמרא ונפרש בו כמו בגמרא. מיהו על כל פנים הרמב''ם והטור לא פליגי כלל. וגם מה שחקרו הגדולים כשגדול יוצא בו בקבע – חקרו בנמנעות לדברינו. ואם אחד עושה כן – בטלה דעתו.
>
> (כן נראה לעניות דעתי. ונראה לי שזה דעת רבי יצחק אבוהב שהובא בבית יוסף אלא שקיצר מאוד. ולפי מה שכתבתי אתי שפיר כל מה שהקשו בזה. וכן מה שכתב המגן אברהם סעיף קטן ב', דאם הגדול מתבייש פטור, עיין שם – וזה אינו, דכיון דחכמים שיערו שבשיעור זה יוצא הגדול עראי מי יחלוק בזה? והמתבייש בטלה דעתו, וכל שיעורי חכמים כן הוא.) ‏
>
> **ד** עוד חקרו הגדולים וצווחו על המנהג שנושאים טליתות קטנים מאוד, ועושין בהן ציצית, והולכין בהם לרשות הרבים בשבת. וצווחו ככרוכיא, וכתבו דלכל הפחות יהיה אורך הטלית אמה וחצי, שלוש רבע אמות מלפניו ושלוש מלאחריו. ואם נחשוב לפי אמות הש''ס, יהיה בשלוש רבע אמה – תשעה ווייערסקעס לפי המידה של מדינתינו רוסיא. ולדבריהם אותם שנושאים קטנים מזה – אינם יוצאים ידי חובת ציצית. כלומר: דזהו כהולך בלא בגד החייב בציצית. ולפי זה אסור לצאת בהם בשבת, דהציצית חשיבי ולא בטלי. ‏
>
> ולכן תמיהני על מי שכתב דמוטב לילך בו מלילך בלא ציצית כלל (מגן אברהם בשם רמ''א), והרי בשבת הוי כמשוי? וכתבו להזהיר ההמון שלא יעשו כן (ט''ז וב''ח וכו'). ולפחות יהיה שלוש רבע אמה אורך בכל צד, וחצי אמה רוחב. והכתפיים יהיו רחבים, כלומר: שהרי פתוח באמצע, ואם לא יהיו רחבים – מיחזי ככולו פתוח. ‏
>
> (מה שכתב המגן אברהם דלא ליתי אוירא דהא גיסא... – פשיטא דאין זה ענין לכאן, ורק במחיצות ובמקום הנחשב כסתום אמרינן כן. אך כוונתו כמו שכתבנו, וכן כתב המחצית השקל.) ‏
>
> **ה** ולעניות דעתי כל חקירה זו בחינם, והעולם מקיימים מצות ציצית בטליתות הקטנים. דכבר בארנו בריש סימן ח מהנימוקי יוסף ומהריטב''א, שיש מהראשונים שאמרו דציצית אינה אלא בבגד שמעטף הראש ורוב הגוף. ולפי זה כל טליתות קטנות שלנו אינם חייבות בציצית. ונדחו דבריהם, ומן התורה כל בגד של ארבע כנפות שנושא על גופו – חייב בציצית, עיין שם. וגם דעת רבינו הבית יוסף כן הוא, כמו שכתבתי שם. ‏
>
> והא דבעינן עיטוף רוב הגוף – זהו בטלית העליון, שהוא כמו הסודר שבזמן הגמרא, שהיה הילוכם בזה כידוע. ולכן מברכינן עלייהו ''להתעטף בציצית''. ובזה בעינן שיעור מפני שהוא על הבגדים. אבל טלית קטן שתחת הבגדים אינה צריכה שיעור כלל, דאם רק יש בו ארבע כנפות – חייב בציצית. וכן מבואר להדיא מדברי הריטב''א והנימוקי יוסף שהבאנו בשם בסעיף ד, עיין שם. ‏